# SVG: How can I grabs paths within coords

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have various paths being generated and added to an SVG group .

Now I have some (x, y, width and height) combinations available. With this I would like to select all paths that fall within this and group them.

Any idea how to identify the paths?

Thanks! -Sri

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the geometric boundingbox of an svg element you can call the getBBox DOM method.

In Raphael, you may use

`Element.getBBox();`

which returns an object with the following properties.

```
x:      number       top left corner x
y:      number       top left corner y
x2:     number       bottom right corner x
y2:     number       bottom right corner y
width:  number       width
height: number       height
```

Refer: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getBBox.